# How to see react changes on refresh on .Net MVC?

Tags: .net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC project using reactjs in some parts of the view. Whenever I make changes in ReactJS and reload the page the changes are not seen. I need to stop the whole application and rebuild it in release mode, and it's a lot of time-consuming. How can I fix this issue?

I haven't use the separate react project it just some page on the application:

[image]

The files inside the source are reactjs and it's for community health SIM as shown in the image. There are  many sim in the project using the react file similarly. How can I do this?

My script in package.json is:

[image]